# hp elitebook 840 g1 ubuntu boot failed

Tags: boot, 16.04

I just complete my Ubuntu installation hp elitebook840 g1.i can run Ubuntu if i choose Ubuntu from boot option pressing f9 during boot. but even i have erase windows while installing Ubuntu the system default boot to windows 8 which was previously installed.
i tried to manage boot order from BIOS but also the problem is same.
how can i configure my system to directly boot Ubuntu.i have gone through several questions and answers but i don't get the solution. any suggestion would be highly appreciated.